# How to implement Graph SSO with a fragment in the URL?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Did not change my code and it worked previously.  It stopped working and worked for a few hours and then stopped again even though I didn't change anything:

```
async signIn(): Promise<void> {
    let result = await this.msalService
        .loginPopup(OAuthSettings.scopes)
        .catch((reason) => { console.log('login failed') });

    if (result) {
        this.authenticated = true;
        this.user = await this.getUser();
    }
}
```

I expect to authenticate like before now I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): GraphError: 
{
  "statusCode": -1,
  "code": null,
  "message": null,
  "requestId": null,
  "date": "2019-07-19T18:08:59.767Z",
  "body": null
}
``

Edit: Found out the issue is because other developers added a fragment to the url.

The code works with no fragment. Localhost:4200/login
But it does not work with the fragment. Localhost:4200/#/login
```

Comment: Are you trying to get User List using Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: I am trying to get the signed in user information after logging in.

Comment: The problem is that the oauth implicit flow doesn't work quite well with the fragement in the url. By the way it's better to not have a fragment in the url anyway.

Comment: I agree, but I don’t have a say in that lol